# How to collapse an SVG element?

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design

I'm trying to make an SVG logo responsive by removing the text and only showing the mark at a certain break point but am running into an issue.  I'm using display: none; to successfully hide the logo's text, but the SVG's full width is still being displayed which leaves a blank area that is still clickable (logo is an anchor).

Relatively new to SVG, and wondering if there is a way to hide/collapse the text so that the width is also reduced to just the logo's mark.  Advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is a Codepen demonstrating the issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVXLmN

```
.logo {
    height: 100px;
}

.logo__text {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {

    .logo__text {
        display: inline-block
    }

}
```